# How much bias am I risking by doing model goodness of fit comparison without accounting for clustering?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, goodness-of-fit, likelihood-ratio, bias-correction

I am interested in testing whether an interaction term is statistically significant or not in a logistic regression. Data is large and observations are clustered by family and suffer from sparsity for both the outcome and one of the covariates in the interaction term (% of 0s vs. 1s are about 95% and 5%).

I first tried (with glmer() in lme4)

```
anova(mixed effects model 1, mixed effects model 2)
```

very simple

```
outcome ~ covar 1 * covar 2 + (1|family)
```

vs.

```
outcome ~ covar 1 + covar 2 + (1|family)
```

Both covar 1 and covar 2 are binary variables. The first model probably ran to the edge of the world after 12 hours and could be found no more. Then I wondered what the cost would be if I ran both models in the same wrong way (i.e., not accounting for the random effect)

Here is a publicly available data set I explored--

```
library(lattice)
gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd), data = cbpp, family = binomial)
cbpp$obs <- 1:nrow(cbpp)
gm2 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd) +  (1|obs), family = binomial, data = cbpp)
anova(gm1,gm2)

# how is it different from lrt?

gm3 <- glm(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + herd,  data = cbpp, family = binomial)
gm4 <- glm(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period * herd,  family = binomial, data = cbpp)
lrtest(gm4,gm3)
```

p from ANOVA = 0.002152, p from LRT = 0.001613

As I was expecting, the LRT was too optimal, but say if the bias (in terms of p-value) is no more than 200% (or some upper limit), a quick way to do model comparison could be running the LRT and multiplying the too-optimal p-values by a scaling factor.

Thank you for your time and insight! Any papers on this would be very helpful, too.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the clustering/correlations in your data can have an impact on the inference you are going to make. The magnitude of ignoring the clustering/correlations in p-values depend on how strong the correlations are, the type of effect you are testing (i.e., within or between clusters effects), any potential missing data you have and the type of mechanism that generated this missing data (i.e., missing completely at random or missing at random).